# Using DFP to serve a Wordpress background image

Tags: wordpress, google-dfp

We currently sell advertising packages on our website that include a mixture of normal banner ads, and also some other value adds like background images, editorial etc.

DFP does a great job managing the display ads, but we'd like to look at a solution that we could load the background image as well.

We're currently using Wordpress as our publishing platform, would it be possible to include in the script somewhere?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly simple to do this... you just need to make a new ad unit which loads a third party creative that uses javascript to change the background of your site... an example of the code to do this can be [found here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/dfp/0aigKPjxj3A/mTi2OYC-8EMJ).